# USB device not found using fdisk

Tags: android, usb, oneplusone

I have a new USB device but I cannot see it usign fdisk command.
Here below some useful info.

```
xxx:~$ uname -a
Linux xxx-laptop 3.2.0-67-generic-pae #101-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jul 15 18:04:54 UTC 2014 i686 athlon i386 GNU/Linux
```

This is the dmesg when I connect the device

```
[ 5025.592149] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 14 using ehci_hcd
```

This is the dmesg when I disconnect the device

```
[ 5076.490468] hub 1-0:1.0: port 1 disabled by hub (EMI?), re-enabling...
[ 5076.490493] usb 1-1: USB disconnect, device number 14
```

This is the device when I type lsusb

```
Bus 001 Device 017: ID 05c6:6764 Qualcomm, Inc.
```

I have tried to add a new rule into /lib/udev/rules.d/69-libmtp.rules

```
ATTR{idVendor}=="05c6", ATTR{idProduct}=="6764", SYMLINK+="libmtp-%k", MODE="666", GROUP="audio", ENV{ID_MTP_DEVICE}="1", ENV{ID_MEDIA_PLAYER}="1"
```

What shall I do?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure the solution proposed applies to OnePlusOne (I assume your case is about this smartphone from the tags). I am giving advice using android 4.2

First, in `Settings-->Other` first check that you have no Usb tethering option set
Then, in `Settings-->Memory` tap on the three `dots` upper right, so you can choose if your device is presenting itself using either MTP or PTP. 
I would guess you won't find any of these two option checked

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I have checked on phone side as you suggested and all seems all right (MTP checked and  USB tethering disabled)